# Mouse isn't moving, clicking is ok

Tags: 20.04, mouse, logitech

my mouse is not moving, but every button on it is working (lef/right klick, forward, backward, scrolling etc).

Setup:

1. Logitech G502 Mouse
2. Asus F550CA Laptop
3. Fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04

What I've tried:

1. Test it on another PC
2. Use a different USB Port
3. xinput list, the G502 is recognized
4. xinput set-prop Accel Speed to 1

But it still isn't working!

Do you have any other suggestions for me?

Comment: It's not clear. When you tested it on another PC, did it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it was a Windows 10 PC and it worked. Plug&Play.